# Hasmany Relationship where first record is current month in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Eloquent with a `HasMany` relationship. I need to filter only `hasmany` relationship if the first record is the current month.

Model

```php
       public function attendanceclasses(){
    
            return $this->hasMany('App\Studentattendance','assign_id','id')->WhereIn('attendance_status',[2,3,6]);
    
        }
    
        public function firstattendadclass(){
    
            return $this->hasOne('App\Studentattendance','assign_id','id')->WhereIn('attendance_status',[2,3,6])->OrderBy('class_date','ASC');
        }
```

Query

```php
                $q->Where('class_date', '>=',date('Y-06-01'));
                $q->Where('class_date','<=',date('Y-m-t'));
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter in `with'. This will filter both parent and child

```
$firstOfMonth= Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->toDateString();
$lastOfMonth=Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()->toDateString();

$stucourselist=StudentCourses::with(['firstattendadclass'=>function($q)use($firstOfMonth,$lastOfMonth){
    $q->Where('class_date', '>=',$firstOfMonth);
    $q->Where('class_date','<=',$lastOfMonth);
}])->whereHas('firstattendadclass',function($q)use($firstOfMonth,$lastOfMonth){
    $q->Where('class_date', '>=',$firstOfMonth);
    $q->Where('class_date','<=',$lastOfMonth);
})->get();
```

if you want to filter only child then you can remove `wherehas`

Also you can use `whereBetween('class_date',[$firstOfMonth,$lastOfMonth])`